# Switching visibilty of a control fed by Javascript causes exception

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a counter on my page that displays the idle time left for a session.
The counter should not always be visible. But when hiding it an exception is thrown although the Javascript that feeds the counter should not be executed in this case:

The C# Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(DIV_Countdown.Visible == true)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Countdown", "SessionCountdown();", true);
    }
```

The Javascript:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SessionCountdown() {
        var seconds = 60;
        $get("<%=LBL_Countdown.ClientID %>").innerHTML = seconds;

        setInterval(function () {
        seconds--;
        $get("<%=LBL_Countdown.ClientID %>").innerHTML = seconds;
        }, 1000);

        setTimeout(function () {
        window.location = "http://essbp1s8000/RRHH/Default.aspx";
        }, seconds * 1000);
    }
</script>
```

The markup:

```
<div id="DIV_Countdown" runat="server" visible="true">Session expires in <asp:label id="LBL_Countdown" runat="server"/ seconds.</div>
```

This works perfect until I switch DIV_Countdown.Visible to false.
JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Did you try to use display style instead of Visible?

Comment: Jitendra, your hint got me on the right path. I can make it work using
DIV_Countdown.Style.Add("display", "show");
to trigger display and
if (DIV_Countdown.Style["display"] == "show")
for the PageLoad check to start JavaScript. BUT: I still need an extra PostBack to display the Figure in LBL_Countdown. Any suggestion how to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a [page lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) problem. If you are setting the visibility of the div on some postback method, it's too late for the Page_Load-event to see that. The Page_Load-event would have been executed before you set the visibility, hence the javascript has been registered already.

I recommend moving the script-block inside the div in the markup so that it can only run if the element is infact visible. That way all you need to worry about it the visibility of the div:

```
<div id="DIV_Countdown" runat="server" visible="true">
    Session expires in
    <asp:Label ID="LBL_Countdown" runat="server" />
    seconds.

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SessionCountdown() {
            var seconds = 60;
                $get("<%=LBL_Countdown.ClientID %>").innerHTML = seconds;

            setInterval(function () {
                seconds--;
                $get("<%=LBL_Countdown.ClientID %>").innerHTML = seconds;
            }, 1000);

            setTimeout(function () {
                window.location = "http://essbp1s8000/RRHH/Default.aspx";
            }, seconds * 1000);
        }

        SessionCountdown();
    </script>
</div>
```

Also if you only need to use the label in the client side (not in server code) I would change that to a

```
<span id="myCountdown"></span>
```

It would make the javascript code much cleaner:

```
document.getElementById("myCountDown").innerHTML...
```

Comment: Yes it looked like a page lifecycle to me too, but I don't know how to fix it. I moved the scriptblock into the div, but as soon as I set DIV_Countdown.Visible to false an exception is raised: "JavaScript runtime error: The value of the property 'SessionCountdown' is null or undefined, not a Function object. Why and who calls the function at that point when the div is invisible???

Comment: If you look at my example, it is calling the function at the end of the script-block. You need to remove the RegisterStartupScript-method call from your Page_Load if you use this method.